# How do I access argv / command line options in Dart?

Tags: command-line-arguments, argv, getopt, dart

And does Dart have a getopt library?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using Options is no longer an option, use:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
   print(args);
}
```

To get executable, use Platform.executable (Platform comes from dart:io)

For parsing arguments passed to main, use this [cool package](https://pub.dev/packages/args)

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This is no longer valid, see accepted answer above.

See `Options`.

http://api.dartlang.org/dart_io/Options.html

```dart
List<String> argv = (new Options()).arguments;
```

Comment: I see that Dart omits the script name from the arguments. Do you know how to retrieve it? Ruby and Perl do it with `$0`.

Comment: Ah, Options has a `script` accessor. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Program_name#Dart

Comment: Small additional comment: as of March 2013 the Options class is in dart:io.

Comment: The `Options` class does no longer exist in dart:io. Use package:args instead.

Answer (score 4):

```js
// dart 1.0 
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  String exec = Platform.executable;
  List<String> flags = Platform.executableArguments;
  Uri    script = Platform.script;

  print("exec=$exec");
  print("flags=$flags");
  print("script=$script");

  print("script arguments:");
  for(String arg in args)
    print(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
#!/usr/bin/env dart

main() {
    print("Args: " + new Options().arguments);
}
```

Comment: Some comments: (1) You do not need to import the core library, (2) the + operator cannot be used as String concatenation, so use "Args: ${new Options().arguments}"

Comment: I think for the version of Dart/Mac OS X I'm using, you do actually have to import `dart:core`. Thank you for the Dart tips. Obviously `+` can be used for string concatenation, because it works in this snippet. Perhaps string interpolation is preferred in Dart, but it is not the only option.

Answer (score 1):

I use this library for defining and parsing command line args http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/args