# How do you pass variables to main in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm using Dart in a Django application. There are configuration parameters that need to be passed to Dart. How do you pass values to main()? At this point I'm considering creating hidden elements in the web page and using query to get the values. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you are building a browser app?

(BTW, you can use `new Options().arguments` for command-line apps. Works great, but obviously there is no command line in browser apps :)

(Second, `main()` doesn't take arguments, so we have to find another way.)

OK, for a browser-app, what I might try doing is embedding some JSON into the page inside a `<script>` tag. Then, using query, find that element, parse the contents, and you're good to go.

In your HTML:

```html
<script id="config">
  {"environment":"test"}
</script>
```

And in your Dart file:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json' as json;

void main() {
  var config = json.parse(query("#config").innerHtml);

  print(config['environment']);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. That's cleaner than what I was thinking of doing.

Comment: This is a fine approach. The other similar approach is to use AJAX/WebSocket to fetch the configuration from the server. The benefit is that you don't need to embed script tags, but the drawback is that it adds latency. I like Seth's approach most. I do also have the habit of *removing* the script tag after using it.

Answer (score 1):

`Options` is not an option anymore.

Now the main function takes arguments.

```dart
main(List<String> args) {
   print(args);
}
```

If you're from python, c, c++. The expectation is that `args[0]` will give the script's path.

But in dart args are only the arguments.

To get the script's path `Platform.script` can be used which is a [`Uri`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html) object. Then `Uri.path` to get the file path as a String.

An example:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main(List<String> args) {
  var dir = Directory.current.path;
  var p = Platform.script.path;
  print("$p called with $args in $dir");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Options](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Options.html) as [seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279541/how-do-i-access-argv-command-line-options-in-dart):

```
#!/usr/bin/env dart

main() {
    print("Args: " + new Options().arguments);
}
```