# How in Dart get command line arguments outside of the `main` method?

Tags: dart, dart-io

In C# langauge exists global system variable for this purpose.

```
Environment.CommandLine
```

This property provides access to the program name and any arguments specified on the command line when the current process was started.

Dart is asynchronous langauge. It allows self starting processes.

```dart
void main() {
  task("foo", callback1);
  task("baz", callback2);
}
```

Package tasks.

```dart
void task(String name, action()) {
  schedule();
  addTask(name. action);
}

void schedule() {
  // Here we start timer if it not started.
  // This timer will get cmd line arguments
  // And executes task specified in cmd line arguments 
}
```

P.S.

An official answer from Dart Team: "Not planned".

I cannot understand: "Why this is possible in other platforms through their libraries but in Dart platform this is not possible?".

Why only through "main" parameters which even not ensures that other isolates not substitute these arguments on the surrogate parameters that are not a real OS process command line arguments)?

Here examples:

## Go language

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println(len(os.Args), os.Args)
}
```

## Rust language

```rust
fn main() {
  let args = os::args();
  println!("The first argument is {}", args[1]);
}
```

## C# language

```csharp
class Sample {
  public static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine();
    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    Console.WriteLine("GetCommandLineArgs: {0}", String.Join(", ", arguments));
  }
}
```

## Ruby language

```ruby
ARGV.each do|a|
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

## Python language

```python
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

## PHP language

```php
foreach($argv as $value)
{
  echo "$value\n";
}
```

## Node.js language

```nodejs
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

P.S.

**Again, I am convinced that that Dart platform is not like everyone else.**

This is only my opinion. It does not change anything.

Thanks, Günter Zöchbauer, for your concern, but do not need to edit this.

Comment: pass arguments to foo or save args pointer and arglen into some global variable.

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279541/how-do-i-access-argv-command-line-options-in-dart) page interesting. It talks about new Options().arguments.

Comment: @Mohit Jain it also says that Options is not available anymore.

Comment: Related issue in the bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18369

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use command-line arguments outside main you have to pass it around. If you want, you can use a global for that.

This behavior is similar to Java, C and C++ (which you forgot to mention).

One big advantage of this approach is, that it is now easy to launch other programs by simply importing them (as a library) and invoking their `main`. It also makes argument handling more consistent with respect to isolates.